# Api gateway and lambda proxy cors problem

Tags: aws-lambda, proxy, aws-api-gateway, apollo-client, apollo-server

I have a problem with CORS in my API gateway lambda proxy. I was trying to struggle with this but still, I get  `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` or `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`.

I use apollo client on frontend where I put 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', header:

```
const authLink = setContext((operation, { headers }) => {
 const token = window.localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
return {
headers: {
  ...headers,
  authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
 }}}
```

Next, as a proxy, I use 'apollo-server-lambda' where I have below handler config:

```
const handler = server.createHandler({
expressGetMiddlewareOptions: {
cors: {
  origin: '*',
  credentials: true,
},}});
```

My graphql API gateway invokes some lambdas, every lambda is wrapped in below wrapper:

```
export const middyfy = (handler: any) => {
return middy(handler).use(middyJsonBodyParser()).use(cors());
};
```

My graphql proxy serverless configuration looks that:

```
 events: [
{
  http: {
    method: 'post',
    path: '/',
    integration: 'lambda-proxy',
    cors: true,
  },
},
{
  http: {
    method: 'get',
    path: '/',
    cors: true,
    integration: 'lambda-proxy',
  },
},
],
```

My API gateway OPTIONS configuration:
[image]

I will be glad for any help

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, browser message was confusing.
In the end, I had the error: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`. It was tricky because It wasn't any problem with CORS. I was passing wrong a Cognito JWT Token in my authorization header. Finally, I didn't need to pass `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',` on the frontend side and use cors middleware on the lambda side.